# Install SciTe editor on Termux

Tags: android, termux, scite

I have tried code debugging on android phone, building web service under Termux. Vim, emacs, mcedit, nano and similars are old-school editors, it is not easy to use after coding in notepad++ for years, so I tried to install SciTe, what is based on scintilla, for in situ edit my code.

[SciTe download](https://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html)

Termux is special distribution for Android, so ok, I have to make it from source.

Download and untargz file, and follow instructions:

```
cd scintilla/gtk
make
```

I get error:

```
No package 'gtk+-2.0' found.
In file included from PlatGTK.cxx:20:
In file included from /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30:
In file included from /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32:10: fatal error: 'glib/gtypes.h' file not found
#include <glib/gtypes.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

How can I install Scintilla?

Comment: You see what has gone wrong ( No package gtk+-2.0 found ), so the installation of the appropriate gtk package would be the solution ... but ... I suppose, as Termux is a non-graphics app, that it will not be possible to run Scite as it needs graphics for its output. Let me know ... I am a vivid user of Scite without any clue about Termux ... which seems to be a very interesting App.

Comment: I dont know what is Termux exactly, it looks like an terminal unix simuation on Android. But I also found this: https://github.com/termux/x11-packages/issues/235 so maybe the developer make package from it?

Comment: I have added the link to the package request to my bookmarks and will eager wait for the comments on it. It would be to good to be true if SciTE could run on Termux, but who knows ... nothing is really impossible ( if SciTE will run, then it should be then theoretically possible to run Python's pyGame or even full Linux Desktop too ... ).